# How to best handle the "Possible vandalism of own posts" flag?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, moderators, moderator-faq

I got a moderator flag saying, "Possible vandalism of own posts; multiple deletions in a short time"; the user is one of my stronger users.

The deleted answers are all over a month old. The flag indicates 5 deleted answers, but there are a total of 8 questions deleted for the user. All the posts are unvoted, so I know it's fair for the user to delete their own answers, but I feel conflicted.

All the posts that were deleted were, IMO, rather good answers. They were large and rather lengthy answers as well, so they really did help contribute to the site.

What am I supposed to do in this situation? Is it fair to send them a system message and ask what's up, or should I comment one of their existing posts? Should I just "continue to monitor"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should contact this user (via the moderator contact option on their user page) and inquire about the posts, indicating that you are concerned because these are good, useful contributions that could help others.

Comment: And if they don't have a great reason for a deletion but still want them deleted, then what?