# "Possible vandalism" (comments) flag is confused about who's who

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

Under (elided) circumstances, a user deleting lots of comments quickly can cause an auto-flag.  It looks something like this:

[image: comment-vandalism flag]

A list of posts with deleted comments follows.

There's just one problem: the user who shows up in the flag view is *not the one doing the deletions*.  (Well, I suppose it *could* be, but I haven't seen it yet.)  I believe this flag is raised on whatever post was the one that kicked the detection algorithm over the threshold.  That makes it hard to scan the flags list *and* hard to handle the flag.

To find out who it's actually about, so I could look at that user's history, I had to go to a linked post, show deleted comments, and go looking for candidates.  If there are self-deleted comments from more than one person, I might have to look at more posts.  That's a lot of work for deleted comments.

Users can't be flagged directly, which is why the flag has to be attached to a post, but there's another "comment stuff in aggregate" flag, the one raised for too many rude/offensive flags.  In that case, while a *post* is flagged, the flag *message* includes the name of the user (and is actually a link for expedited handling).  Could we have that for vandalism flags too?

That is, something like this:

[image: show user name and link to history]

Apparently it [used to identify the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168250/162102), years ago.  (And I guess it used to be a 10k tool instead of mod-only.)

I don't see this flag very often, so every time I do I have to remind myself that it's not what it appears at first glance to be.